# Having trouble running OpenGL on MSVC

Tags: opengl, c++, glut, glew

I'm using the  OpenGL Programming Guide, 8th Edition with MSVC 2013 but I can't get the triangles.cpp file to run.

These are the errors popping up:
http://puu.sh/jAokn/c07420cf46.png

[image: Errors from MSVC]

Comment: Apparently, it can't locate the implementation of your glew, and of your loadshader methods. Did you forget to add a .lib file to your list of library files to include when linking?

Comment: This is the directory that is on the textbook website:
http://puu.sh/jApbj/7f6e13bf2c.png     And I have it set as a Library Directory here: http://puu.sh/jApPu/93eab42310.jpg

Comment: Adding the _path_ to where it is located is not sufficient, you actually have to specify the name of the .lib.

Comment: I have no clue which .lib file to link to

Comment: It's hard to tell from here... try them all :P Or you might try and find a tool that lists exported methods from libraries...

Comment: I tried linking all the .lib files and got the same errors.